# File Upload and sending info via POST request to API

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo-server

So I have a mutation that takes a single file. It needs to read the file and send a POST request with the data to an API. Currently, I'm somehow not reading the stream correctly and sending the info via a POST request to my api without any file information.

I'm not quite sure how to read the file properly. Also Apollo server only does json and not multiform data. If I use axios it then messes with the typings of the data types I have.

What am I missing here?

[Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/requests/#postRequests)

Schema:

```
input UploadDocumentType {
  file: Upload!
}
type Task {
  filename: String!
  mimetype: String!
  encoding: String!
  id: ID!
}

type UploadDocumentPayload {
  file: Task
}
type Mutation {
 uploadDocument(input: UploadDocumentType!): UploadDocumentPayload
}
```

I have basic data returning here below. But I want to grab the ID from the response.

Resolver:

```
const Mutation: MutationResolvers = {
  async uploadDocument(_, args: MutationUploadDocumentArgs, ctx: Context) {
    const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await args.input.file
    const res = ctx.dataSources.taskService.postTask(createReadStream);

    return { 
      file: {filename, mimetype, encoding, id} 
    }
  }
}
```

I have two versions of the task. One with Axios and another with Apollo-server's RESTDataSource

```
async postTask(file: Scalars["Upload"]) {
    const url = process.env.BASE_TASK_URL
    return this.post(`${url}/task/`, {
      "task_type": "brief-analysis",
      "binary_payload": file
    })
  }


  async postTask(file: Scalars["Upload"]) {
    const url = process.env.BASE_TASK_URL
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("file", file)

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        // "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      },
      data: formData
    };
    return axios.post(`${url}/task/`, formData, config).then(res => res.data).catch(e => console.log("in post req", e))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Send file as binary value

```
var file = files.item(0);
var binaryFile = '';
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = e => {
  binaryFile = reader.result
};
reader.readAsDataURL(this.invoice.file);
```